# InvalidOperationException: Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type 'TextBlock'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have created a style called baseStyle like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="baseStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Saumil_guj2" />
</Style>
```

Then I used it for a ListBoxItem like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">

</Style>
```

It happily accepts the `FontSize` and `FontFamily` from `baseStyle`.

I tried to do a similar thing for TextBlock:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">

</Style>
```

Now its complaining. I mean It gave me exeption:

```
InvalidOperationException: Can only base on a Style with target type 
that is base type 'TextBlock'.
```

So, I checked on MSDN.

There I found that ListBoxItem derives indirectly from System.Windows.Controls. It can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx).

There I also found that TextBlock also derives from System.Windows.Controls. It can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, I don't understand why am I getting this error?

Comment: `TextBlock` does not derive from `Control` but straight from `FrameworkElement`. There is no common class between `TextBlock` and `Control` that has `FontSize` and `FontFamily`. They both implement it separately

Comment: @dkozl You should make that as answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment `TextBlock` does not derive from `Control` but straight from `FrameworkElement`. There is no common class between `TextBlock` and `Control` that has `FontSize` and `FontFamily`. They both implement it separately. What you could do it create style for `FrameworkElement` that sets attached properties `TextElement.FontSize` and `TextElement.FontFamily`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="baseStyle">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Saumil_guj2" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">

</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">

</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks @dkozl. That works perfectly. I tried FrameworkElement just after posting posting this question and I got another error as it does not contain FontSize and FontFamily. Now I learnt a new lesson. I should use TextElement.FontSize in such cases. Thank you once again.